# How to zoom-in 120%, 150%, and 180% on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

Thank you for reading my post.

I am using Magnific Popup - zoom function.
I wanna know how to set the zoom in %,
and how to have 3 different degrees of zooming-in by clicking on the popup image.

Just want to clarify my obstacle:
For example, I want to click on the magnific popup image then zoom-in to 120%, second click, zoom-in to 150%, third click, zoom-in to 180%, then the fourth click, will zoom-out back to 100%.

Does anyone know how to do that?
If does, it helps me a lot.
Thank you so so much!

The original code (works):

```
$('#img').magnificPopup({ 
          delegate: 'a',
          type: 'image',
          callbacks: {
              open: function() {
                $(".mfp-figure figure").css("cursor", "zoom-in");
                $(".mfp-figure figure").zoom({ 
                    on: "click",
                    onZoomIn: function () {
                        $(this).css("cursor", "zoom-out");
                    },
                    onZoomOut: function () {
                        $(this).css("cursor", "zoom-in");
                    }
                });
              },
              close: function() {
                // Will fire when popup is closed
              }
              // e.t.c.
            }
        });
```

My code (didn't work):

```
$('#img').magnificPopup({ 
          delegate: 'a',
          type: 'image',
          callbacks: {
              open: function() {
                $(".mfp-figure figure").css("cursor", "zoom-in");
                $(".mfp-figure figure").zoom({ 
                    on: "click",
                    onZoomIn: function () {
                        $(this).zoom({
                            on: "click",
                            onZoomIn: function(){
                            },
                            onZoomOut: function(){
                            }
                        });
                        $(this).css("cursor", "zoom-out");
                    },
                    onZoomOut: function () {
                        $(this).css("cursor", "zoom-in");
                    }
                });
              },
              close: function() {
                // Will fire when popup is closed
              }
              // e.t.c.
            }
        });
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Added. Thanks for your remind. :)  I am new on this platform.

Answer (score 6):

At last, I gave up the Magnifier Popup - zoom function, and replace it with css - zoom function.

The solution:

```
`var zoom_percent = "100";
        function zoom(zoom_percent){
            $(".mfp-figure figure").click(function(){
                switch(zoom_percent){
                    case "100":
                        zoom_percent = "120";
                        break;
                    case "120":
                        zoom_percent = "150";
                        break;
                    case "150":
                        zoom_percent = "200";
                        $(".mfp-figure figure").css("cursor", "zoom-out");
                        break;
                    case "200":
                        zoom_percent = "100";
                        $(".mfp-figure figure").css("cursor", "zoom-in");
                        break;
                }
                $(this).css("zoom", zoom_percent+"%");
            });
        }

        $('#img').magnificPopup({ 
          delegate: 'a',
          type: 'image',
          callbacks: {
              open: function() {
                  $(".mfp-figure figure").css("cursor", "zoom-in");
                  zoom(zoom_percent);
              },
              close: function() {
                // Will fire when popup is closed
              }
              // e.t.c.
            }

        });`
```

Hope this helps someone who is also looking for it.

Comment: Hi, is there any way if i click on it, it zooms on center ? And thanks for this answer. this saved my day.

Comment: thanks so much, took me the whole afternoon to find your solution. Seems to be more niche than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the below code. It is a simple example which you can modify according to your code.

```
$("img").click(function(){
    var zoom = parseInt($(this).css("zoom"));
    if(zoom==180){
        $(this).css("zoom","100%");
    }else{
        $(this).css("zoom",zoom+20+"%");
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, your answer inspired me :)

Comment: You need to accept any answer by clicking check mark on left side. If you find this answer useful, accept it.